# grid view printing with table in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, database

i am using visual studio 2008 and sql server 2008

i want to print my **"gridview with table"** using a button 
in asp.net 3.5 
code has three part first this is from my default page

```
 protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["ctrl"] = Panel1;
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onclick",
        "<script language=javascript>window.open('Print.aspx','PrintMe','height=300px,width=300px,scrollbars=1');</script>");
    PrintHelper.PrintWebControl(Panel1);
}
```

this code this from print page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control ctrl = (Control)Session["ctrl"];
    PrintHelper.PrintWebControl(ctrl);
}
```

and this is my print helper class

```
 public PrintHelper()
{
}

public static void PrintWebControl(Control ctrl)
{
    PrintWebControl(ctrl, string.Empty);
}

public static void PrintWebControl(Control ctrl, string Script)
{
    StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
    if (ctrl is WebControl)
    {
        Unit w = new Unit(100, UnitType.Percentage); ((WebControl)ctrl).Width = w;
    }
    Page pg = new Page();
    pg.EnableEventValidation = false;
    if (Script != string.Empty)
    {
        pg.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(pg.GetType(), "PrintJavaScript", Script);
    }
    HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
    pg.Controls.Add(frm);
    frm.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
    frm.Controls.Add(ctrl);
    pg.DesignerInitialize();
    pg.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    string strHTML = stringWrite.ToString();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strHTML);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>window.print();</script>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

please help me out

Comment: this question is too vague. more details needed: where, what....

Comment: i have created a web page that prints my grid view it shows the data in gridview but the problem is it does not show's me the rows and columns of grid view

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far so we're not guessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Data Adapter, create a Command Object with a Select query, set the adapter's command to this command object, issue an adapter.fill(dataset), set the data source of gridview as the dataset and databind the GridView.

For code, a simple Google search will work. You did not even specify a language. I guess you are working in C# and this is your college project. Is it?

Comment: yes u r right its a online banking project i want  to print statement of  bank but i don't want to use crystal report my datasource is working fine it gets the data frm database issue is that i want table's and row to seen in printed page

Comment: In that case, create a new print functionality and use it to redirect to a page with only the Grid View. If you have seen enough of bank websites, you will see that banks generally put this in a JavaScript and it opens a new pop-up window with only the gridview table and a print button. Especially, the Indian railways website. At any point of time, you should consider Crystal Reports as it is a new feaure in .NET and will add considerable value to your project.

Answer (score 2):

maybe this can help.

public class GridViewExportUtil
{

```
    public static void Export(string fileName, GridView gv)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1254");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "windows-1254"; //ISO-8859-13 ISO-8859-9  windows-1254

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader(
            "content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        string header = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\n<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n<head>\n<title></title>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=windows-1254\" />\n<style>\n</style>\n</head>\n<body>\n";

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                //  Create a form to contain the grid
                Table table = new Table();
                table.GridLines = GridLines.Horizontal;
                //table.CellSpacing = 17;

                //  add the header row to the table
                if (gv.HeaderRow != null)
                {
                    GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(gv.HeaderRow);
                    table.Rows.Add(gv.HeaderRow);
                }

                //  add each of the data rows to the table
                foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
                {
                    GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(row);
                    table.Rows.Add(row);
                }

                //  add the footer row to the table
                if (gv.FooterRow != null)
                {
                    GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(gv.FooterRow);

                    table.Rows.Add(gv.FooterRow);
                    //table.Height = 17;
                }

                //  render the table into the htmlwriter
                table.RenderControl(htw);

                //  render the htmlwriter into the response
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(header + sw.ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Replace any of the contained controls with literals
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="control"></param>
    private static void PrepareControlForExport(Control control)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < control.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            Control current = control.Controls[i];
            if (current is LinkButton)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as LinkButton).Text));
            }
            else if (current is ImageButton)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as ImageButton).AlternateText));
            }
            else if (current is HyperLink)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as HyperLink).Text));
            }
            else if (current is DropDownList)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text));
            }
            else if (current is CheckBox)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as CheckBox).Checked ? "True" : "False"));
            }
            else if (current is Label)
            {
                control.Controls.Remove(current);
                control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as Label).Text));
            }

            if (current.HasControls())
            {
                GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(current);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, get your data displaying in the GridView (there are about a bazillion resources on this site and other to show you how to do that).

Here's the javascript to print the window:

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="window.print()">
```

Comment: but this will print the whole page i only need my data gridview to be printed

Comment: Then you'll have to make a page that only has your data gridview.