# Dynamically retriving data is not visible from Print Preview

Tags: javascript, .net

I am having a web page, which has one button on it. Pressing on this button I am calling jquery and getting the data and displaying into the GridView...

On same screen I have Print button which calls WIndows.Print() simple javascript...
But it doesn't print this Gridview,
Even when I tried directly from the browser, it doesn't come up. Anyone has clue what could be the problem..

Comment: What is "Gridview"? A plug-in? A server-side control?

Comment: GridView a asp.net control which renders at runtime as html table. So basically when we go for view source it shows the correct tabular html.

Answer (score 0):

The gridview is not made to be printed.  You will need to extract the datasource and put in a printable view.  Here is some examples:

1. [grid view printing with table in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134090/grid-view-printing-with-table-in-asp-net)
2. http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2008/02/printing-gridview-from-aspnet.html